# Sorting list of objects by date field in Java

Tags: java, mysql, date, jpa

I've been trying many, many, (really, many) codes to make my list of objects be ordered by a date field, trying comparators, lambda, and a long etc...

Nothing I have done worked, my list is just not ordering and I really don't know what else to do, I have search in here many times and tried everything I found.

I have a list of posts, has a java.util.Date field called *created*, these posts has a many-to-many relationship with a entity called category.

First I created a category:

```
Category cat = catCtrl.get(5);
```

Then I get the list of posts:

```
List<Post> list = cat.getPostList();
```

Printing out the list: (ID + created + title)

> 45 Sat Nov 25 03:36:06 MST 2017 Donec a libero lacinia
>   46 Mon Nov 27 02:46:37 MST 2017 Etiam at bibendum mauris
>   47 Sat Nov 25 03:39:17 MST 2017 Cras vel orci nunc
>   50 Sat Nov 25 03:37:29 MST 2017 dasdasf

Now, the idea is to get the list ordered by created date from recent to old:

> 46 Mon Nov 27 02:46:37 MST 2017 Etiam at bibendum mauris
>   47 Sat Nov 25 03:39:17 MST 2017 Cras vel orci nunc
>   50 Sat Nov 25 03:37:29 MST 2017 dasdasf
>   45 Sat Nov 25 03:36:06 MST 2017 Donec a libero lacinia

According to official documentation, this should do it:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Post>() {
    public int compare(Post p1, Post p2) {
        return p1.getCreated().compareTo(p2.getCreated());
    }
});
```

However that code doesn't change the order at all.

What I have been missing?

Comment: Please post enough of the code you have written so that others can run your code and see what the problem is. That will help this question get answered more quickly.

Comment: Are you retrieving these posts from a database?  Most likely you should be doing the ordering in the database via an `ORDER BY` clause.  Also, the dates do not appear to be in standard format.  Are you storing your dates as text?

Comment: Is the datetime column nullable? Are you getting any NPE's?

Comment: Yes, from a MySQL database, they are stored as _datetime_ type.
The problem when I tried to use the ORDER BY clause is the join table when creating the NamedQuery, for some reason I have the SQL query but Im getting an error:
**The abstract schema type 'postCategory' is unknown**
`SELECT p FROM Post AS p LEFT JOIN postCategory AS pc ON p.id = pc.post LEFT JOIN Category AS c ON pc.category = c.id WHERE c.id = :category AND p.status = :status AND p.city = :city ORDER BY p.created DESC`

Comment: @PankajGadge, the MySQL column is not-nullable and not, I dont get any error, exception, anything, just the list is the same order I got it from database.

Comment: Why can't you use `java.sql.date`?

Comment: Why? are java.util.Date not orderable?

Comment: What type are you specifying in your JPA query while doing `ps.setObject(fieldIndex, utilDateObject);`?

Comment: @Poxxac could you solve the issue? You can see from the answer below that your code for sorting should work. Maybe you have some other issue? When do you check whether the sorting worked? Maybe there is the issue? Can you share a minimal sample code please?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code. Could you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please?

Comment: `java.util.Date` are comparable, so ordering them the way you try should work.

Comment: Both `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` are long outdated, so there’s no point in changing from one to the other (and you could even lose your time-of-day information). Instead, do consider changing to [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API also known as JSR-310](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is generally much nicer to work with than the old classes.

Comment: An important detail, to get the order from most recent to oldest you will need to reverse the sign of the return value from `compare()`.

Answer (score 0):

@Poxxac

Use below code, worked for me.

```
package com.java;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;
import com.google.common.collect.MultimapBuilder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

        Example example1 = new Example();
        example1.setDate(new Date());
        example1.setName("Name1");

        Example example2 = new Example();
        example2.setDate(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-48*60*60*1000));
        example2.setName("Name2");

        Example example3 = new Example();
        example3.setDate(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-24*60*60*1000));
        example3.setName("Name3");

        Multimap<String, Example> multimap = MultimapBuilder.treeKeys().linkedListValues().build();
        multimap.put(df.format(example1.getDate()), example1);
        multimap.put(df.format(example2.getDate()), example2);
        multimap.put(df.format(example3.getDate()), example3);


        System.out.println(multimap);

    }
}

class Example {

    private String name;

    private Date date;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Example [name=" + name + ", date=" + date + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this helps?! You're creating a sorted multimap where the keys are string values. And now?

Comment: @AKSW Here the Multi Map code automatically sorts based on the key once you put your data in it. Execute and check the output.

Comment: This is overcomplicating things. We just need the sorting of the list to work.

Comment: @Kumar I know that sorting on string keys works, it's trivial and similar to `TreeMap`. But that's not the question here. He wants to sort a list of items by a particular attribute of the item.

Answer (score 0):

A test function:

```
public void test()
{
    Date date1 = DateUtils.convertToDate("2017-11-20");
    Date date2 = DateUtils.convertToDate("2017-11-21");
    Date date3 = DateUtils.convertToDate("2017-11-22");

    Demo demo1 = new Demo(1, date1);
    Demo demo2 = new Demo(2, date2);
    Demo demo3 = new Demo(3, date3);
    List<Demo> demos = new ArrayList<Demo>();
    demos.add(demo1);
    demos.add(demo2);
    demos.add(demo3);

    for(Demo item : demos){
        System.out.println(item.toString());
    }

    Collections.sort(demos, new Comparator<Demo>(){
        public int compare(Demo o1, Demo o2){
            return o2.create.compareTo(o1.create);
        }
    });
    System.out.println("========== ordered =============");
    for(Demo item : demos){
        System.out.println(item.toString());
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
1-Mon Nov 20 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2017
2-Tue Nov 21 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2017
3-Wed Nov 22 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2017
========== ordered =============
3-Wed Nov 22 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2017
2-Tue Nov 21 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2017
1-Mon Nov 20 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2017
```

There is another question that you may be using the class `java.util.LinkedList` to story these `datas`.

**Note**: the class `DateUtils` is my own definition.